# CodeBuild trigger using custom buildstep file for specific folders

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

I've been calling codebuild and manually overriding the buildspec like this:

```
aws codebuild start-build --cli-input-json file://servicea/custom.json
```

and then in `custom.json`

```
{
    "projectName": "myproject",
    "sourceVersion": "master",
    "buildspecOverride": "servicea/buildspec.yml"
}
```

Now I want to use bitbucket trigger (or github if bitbucket is not supported) to build the service automatically after it's being pushed to master.

I've been Googling and found this tutorial https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/sample-bitbucket-pull-request.html

However, I met a roadblock where I couldn't build a specific folder with a specific buildspec.

e.g.

1. for `servicea`, the build should run if I push to master and change any files in `servicea` folder with `servicea/buildspec.yaml` as the buildspec
2. for `serviceb`, the build should run if I push to master and change any files in `serviceb` folder with `serviceb/buildspec.yaml` as the buildspec

There is a `FILE_PATH` filter in the trigger, however there's I couldn't find a way to set the custom buildspec.

Is there any way to achieve this?

**Note:**
I want to use 1 codebuild project for all of my services

Answer (score 0):

Bitbucket's webhook payload doesn't have the list of files changed in them, unlike GitHub.

Workaround:
Set the "git-credential-helper" to "yes" (or true) in your buildspec. Details in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-spec-ref.html#build-spec-ref-syntax

You can then fetch the list of file changed for the specific commit using the call mentioned in https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Bitbucket-How-to-get-modified-files-of-a-commit-in-JSON-format/qaq-p/704126

You can obtain the commit from the environment variable: CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION and the branch from: CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_HEAD_REF. Details in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-env-vars.html